# Crystal Reports Group Header edit

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to figure out how to change or edit Group Header titles in Crystal Reports.  Group Header title is pulled from  sql and I only have two Group Headers and it's the second one I need to edit.  It reads SEP which is pulled from data table, but for reporting purpose I'd like it to read Separate Accounts.  Group Headers are not text objects, so I don't know how to edit.  Thanks.

Comment: how are you displayng the value from database in report?

Answer (score 0):

click on the group Tab  then  Properties
so you can change the name[image]

Answer (score -1):

What version of Crystal Reports are you using?  Exactly how do you want to edit the titles?

In the grey area of the designer, right click on the group you want to edit, select change group and look for 'Customize Group Field Name'.  Depending on what version (I am looking at Crystal 2011 right now), you can choose another field or Use a Formula as a Group Name.  I think that the latter should suit your needs.  Create a formula (you will have to know how to use Crystal formula logic) to modify/append your groupname tiles.

Alternatively, you could make title changes in the SQL itself using SQL functions, CASE statement, etc.

I hope this helps